# Injecting Javascript in a page from a Chrome extension : concurrency issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am taking part in the development of a Chrome extension.

At some point, we need to run some static non-generated code which has to run in the context of the page and not of the extension.

For simple scripts, there is no problem, using either `$.getScript(chrome.extension.getURL(....))` either `script = document.createElement('script'); ... document.body.appendChild(script);`

For more complex scripts, we'd need sometimes to incluque jquery itself, or some other script definition (because of dependencies).

In this latter case, though, despite the fact that Javascript is supposedly single threaded, it seems that JQuery is not parsed entirely when the dependend script are run, leading to the following

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Am I wrong when assuming that JScript is single-threaded?
What is the correct way to inject scripts in a page when there are dependencies between those scripts? (e.g. script X uses a function defined in script Y)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the onload event for the script....

```
function addScript(scriptURL, onload) {
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.setAttribute("type", "application/javascript");
   script.setAttribute("src", scriptURL);
   if (onload) script.onload = onload;
   document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
}

function addSecondScript(){
    addScript(chrome.extension.getURL("second.js"));
}

addScript(chrome.extension.getURL("jquery-1.7.1.min.js"), addSecondScript);
```

Comment: That worked. I wrote a chaining mechanism, but using the onload attribute does exactly what is needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Appending a `script` element with `src` attribute in the DOM doesn't mean that the script is actually loaded and ready to be used. You will need to monitor when the script has actually loaded, after which you can start using jQuery as normal.

You could do something like this:

```
    var script = doc.createElement("script");
    script.src = url;
    /* if you are just targeting Chrome, the below isn't necessary        
    script.onload = (function(script, func){
        var intervalFunc; 

        if (script.onload === undefined) {
            // IE lack of support for script onload

            if( script.onreadystatechange !== undefined ) {

                intervalFunc = function() {
                    if (script.readyState !== "loaded" && script.readyState !== "complete") {
                        window.setTimeout( intervalFunc, 250 );

                    } else {
                        // it is loaded
                        func();

                    }

                };

                window.setTimeout( intervalFunc, 250 );

            } 

        } else {
            return func;
        }

    })(script, function(){

       // your onload event, whatever jQuery etc.
    });
    */
    script.onload = onreadyFunction; // your onload event, whatever jQuery etc.

    document.body.appendChild( script );
```